# Can I iterate through multiple arrays in Handlebars

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

A bit of a tall order here but I want to pass this array/set to handlebars

```
  var thisWeek = {
    date: "18-3-13",
    comment: "Run through days of the week",
    days:[{
    monday:[
      {vehicle: "Number 1", driver: "Jack_Franklin", events: "Boat Race"},
      {vehicle: "Number 2", driver: "Paul Smith", events: "Racing"},
      {vehicle: "Number 3", driver: "Andrew Kay", events: "Skiing"} 
      ],
    tuesday:[
      {vehicle: "Number 1", driver: "Jack_Franklin", events: "pick up trailer"},
      {vehicle: "Number 2", driver: "Paul Smith", events: "MOT "},
      {vehicle: "Number 3", driver: "Andrew Kay", events: "Park up for day"} 
      ],
    }],
  }
```

What I want to do is iterate though the days of the week and list all the vehicles on that day , something like -

```
    <script id="ajax-comment" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

    {{#each days}}
    <h2> {{ The day of the week ie Monday - Tuesday etc}}  </h2> 

           {{# each vehicle in monday etc }} 
             {{vehicle}}: {{driver}} : {{events}} <br/>
           {{/each }} 

    {{/each }}  

    </script>
```

I can pass an array with just the monday details and it will work for me but is there anyway that I can do the lot at once?, ideally i want to pass the details of maybe 15 vehicles per day over around 20 days.. hope this makes sense ? , any help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... Assuming you can change the structure to be:

```
{
    days: [{
        day: "Monday",
        vehicles: [{vehicle: "Number 1", driver: "Jack_Franklin", events: "pick up trailer"}]
    }, {
        day: "Tuesday",
        vehicles: [{vehicle: "Number 1", driver: "Jack_Franklin", events: "pick up trailer"}]
    }]
}
```

... You should be able to do that like this;

```
{{#each days}}
    <h2>The day of the week is {{day}} </h2>

    {{#each vehicles}}
        {{vehicle}}: {{driver}} : {{events}} <br />
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, That is absolutely what I wanted to achieve !